# Tweetsharp: Retrieve list of tweets from a specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net, tweetsharp

Couldn't find this in the official TS documentation, other Tweetsharp SO posts, or digging through the library's classes; so I thought I'd ask. How do you retrieve a list of the most recent Tweets from a specific user using Tweetsharp?

You can assume I'm authenticating with an account that is following the user whom's tweets I want to retrieve. I may even be able to authenticate with the account of the user itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use ListTweetsOnSpecifiedUserTimeline().

For example:

```
var service = new TwitterService(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);
var currentTweets = service.ListTweetsOnSpecifiedUserTimeline(screenName:"screen name", page:1, count:100);
```

Comment: Totally missed that method. Thanks Ronald!

Comment: how do we know that whether the count is less or more than the 100 ?

Comment: @CanCeylan That number depicts page size. One page will have max 100 records.

Answer (score 1):

The method is a little different in updated versions. Its now called
ListTweetsOnUserTimeline()

and it your going to pass through options now like so:

```
  var currentTweets = service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions
                {
                    ScreenName = "yourTwitterHandle",
                    Count = 5,
                });
```